# Simulate file alteration monitor (FAM) event

Tags: c, linux

I want to simulate a FAM event.  The API doesn't seem to support this.
Why? Because I have a thread waiting on a FAMNextEvent() and I want to wake it up from another thread.
I guess I could touch one of the files being monitored but that seems very crude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `FAMNextEvent` directly, how about using `select` or `poll` on

- `FAMCONNECTION_GETFD(FAMConnection)`
  When it triggers, check `FAMPending` before calling `FAMNextEvent`.
- a [self-pipe](http://cr.yp.to/docs/selfpipe.html)

The thread will wait for either a FAM event *or* a byte written to the self-pipe.

Comment: Thanks!  Great idea.  I didn't know FAM was using select under the hood.  But makes sense.  Looking around I read pselect() makes a self-pipe obsolete.  But I prefer the idea of writing a byte to the self-pipe to sending a signal.

Comment: @mikejones Handling signals in a multi-threaded program is... tricky.  You'd be better off with `signalfd` or avoiding signals.

Comment: It took me quite some time to make this work.  I found that when it comes out of the select() and I call FAMPending().  Pending would report no events but if I went back to waiting with select() it waited forever.  So I dropped the FAMPending() and went right to FAMNextEvent().  Then I had another bug... it wasn't getting all the events.  The solution was to check for pending events after the FAMNextEvent() and, of course, if there were any go back to FAMNextEvent.